# How to test session.clear() in Mocking unit test

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, nunit, moq

How can i test a method which clear the session and logoff user.

my controller method looks like

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public ActionResult LogOff()
  {
    SessionAdapter.Clear();
    SessionAdapter.Abandon();         
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut
                     (DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
  }
```

Here session adapter is my static class

```
public static class SessionAdapter
  {
    private static string sessionKey = "sessionInfoKey";

    public static SessionInfo Instance
    {
      get
      {
        return HttpContext.Current.Session[sessionKey] == null ? null : (SessionInfo)HttpContext.Current.Session[sessionKey];
      }
      set
      {
        HttpContext.Current.Session[sessionKey] = value;
      }
    }

    public static bool DoesSessionExists { get { return HttpContext.Current.Session[sessionKey] == null ? false : true; } }

    public static void Clear()
    {
      HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear();
    }
}
```

Please help me

Answer (score 2):

In a unit test you should mocking out session since it's an external dependency.  Your unit tests should be testing your code, not the .net framework.

So a valid test might be to verify that a call to Session.Clear happened, not actually testing Session.Clear clears out a session.

This can be done by setting up a fake session.  Here's a extension method I use to setup my controller context for unit testing

public static void SetControllerContext(this Controller controller)
        {
            var fakeContext = A.Fake();
            var fakeRequest = A.Fake();
            var fakeResponse = A.Fake();
            var fakeSessionState = A.Fake();

```
        A.CallTo(() => fakeRequest.HttpMethod).Returns(HttpVerbs.Post.ToString());
        A.CallTo(() => fakeContext.Response).Returns(fakeResponse);
        A.CallTo(() => fakeContext.Request).Returns(fakeRequest);
        A.CallTo(() => fakeContext.Session).Returns(fakeSessionState);

        var fakeRequestContext = new RequestContext(fakeContext, new RouteData());

        controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(fakeRequestContext, controller);
    }
```

This is using FakeItEasy, but the same thing can be done with Moq.

From [MS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) "ASP.NET session state enables you to store and retrieve values for a user as the user navigates ASP.NET pages in a Web application."

What's the value in wrapping that in a static class?